# insert into table values from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

I want to insert into table values from array.

```
var theFields = 
    "my_id,"+ 
    "fruit,"+...

var theData = [
    my_id,
    req.body.fruit,...
     ]
```

I can do:

```
client.query("INSERT INTO theTable("+ theFields +") values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,...." +
```

but I want to avoid the "$1,$2..so on "

So, I tried :

```
client.query("INSERT INTO theTable("+ theFields +")  values($1::varchar[])",[theData], function(err, result) {

client.query("INSERT INTO theTable("+ theFields +")  values ANY($1::varchar[])",[theData], function(err, result) {
```

but they don't work.

Note,that the fields are of the same type , varchar.

( Also,if I have different types ,is there a way to accomplish this using some solution like the one I am trying? )

Comment: That's a bad idea, because variables provide proper escaping for strings, also protecting against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can compose string `$1,$2,...` programatically. I assume that length of  `theData` array is equal to the count of fields in your query:

```
var values = theData.map(function(f, i) {
    return "$" + (i + 1);
}).join();
client.query("INSERT INTO theTable(" + theFields + ")  values(" + values + ")", ...
```

Comment: :It gives `TypeError: theFields.map is not a function`
`

Comment: :In the query,after the `values(" + values + ")",` should I have `values(" + values + ")",theData,function(err,result){` , or `[theData],function(err,result){ ` or something else , because it hangs.